# Angular 7 - Change background colour of component

Tags: css, angular

I am starting out in Angular so please excuse if this is a bit of a noob question. I have generated a component that I would like to use as the login screen. I am trying to change the background color of the entire page but can't do so successfully.

I have tried the following:

```
html{
    background-color: blue !important;
}

body{
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Which doesn't work. I do not want to change the background colour of all the pages, only this login component. So putting the above code into the `styles.scss` file isn't an option.

Comment: wrap the login html inside a wrapper with position absolute, margin 0, top 0 and left 0, width 100% and height 100vh. Then you can change the wrapper background color as you want and all the page will be blue

Comment: Worked like a charm - thanks @JacopoSciampi

Comment: You're welcome :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:host {
    background: blue;
}
```

You should read some docs on [Component styling](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles), especially [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation)
This mecanism ensure that style defined only apply to the component and do not "leak" around.